# What is the default format of date in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

I am passing the date from a Salesforce `web to lead` form to Salesforce.I am passing the date in `MM/DD/YY` format but it is not getting saved in the Salesforce.

What may be the reason?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For date only field pass the date in these date formats `MM/dd/yyyy` or `yyyy-MM-dd`. Check [this thread](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gl7rAAA) for more information